# Rebuild a non clustered PK into a clustered one?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

For a Products table with a NON clustered PK,  and no clustered index at all: is it possible using `ALTER INDEX..REBUILD` (or any simple method) to change the `NON CLUSTERED` PK into a `CLUSTERED` one ? How ?
I would be delighted to avoid a DROP, since there are other tables with constraints that are preventing me for dropping Products PK.

---

EDIT:
I found that using *TOAD for SQL Server* (I have the free *community edition*), I can right click a table, select Alter Table, change Clustered from False to True and it generates a frightening - but working - script, where it creates a new table, copies data, drops and re-create/rename everything it needs to.
However, I still hope there is a recommended way to do this with a special tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the clustered index using the `DROP_EXISTING = ON` option. You can also create a primary key that way if you prefer to do that.

---

```
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT *
INTO o
FROM sys.objects

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX sjhfg ON o (object_ID)
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX sjhfg ON o (object_ID) WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)

SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('o')

ROLLBACK
```

Comment: I did not find a way to change the CLUSTERED property using CREATE with DROP_EXISTING = ON. How would you do that ?

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: To be clear: Being clustered is not a property that can be changed on the index. SQL Server is very inconsistent with its index syntax DDL. Some properties of an index can only be changed using the DROP_EXISTING syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The majority of articles / answers indicate that this is not possible. However, as indicated in the answer by @usr, it is possible to convert a NonClustered index into a Clustered index. Since we are dealing with a PK, that requires:

- first dropping all FKs that reference this PK
- Ignoring the constraint portion of the PK and simply recreate the index portion of the PK as UNIQUE CLUSTERED
- Finally, recreate all of the FKs that were dropped in Step 1

If this is a very large table and you cannot afford the time that this table will be locked, or if you cannot afford the possibility of orphaned data for operations that happen on the related tables while this operation is happening, you should do the following to reduce the time it takes to do the switch:

1. Create a duplicate table named [CurrentName_new] with a clustered PK
2. Migrate the data
3. Drop and recreate the FKs on the dependent tables to point to the new table
4. Rename the current table to [CurrentName_old]
5. Rename the new table to [CurrentName]

Comment: Indeed, this is what TOAD (see my edit) seems to do.